# How to press shift+a = ctrl+s in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

.
Please for you help. .
I want to press **shift+a = ctril+s** in autohotkeys, ,

I already try this

```
#Persistent
send +{s}::
Send ^{a}
return
```

But still can't.
Is there have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You want to press **shift+a** and run **ctrl+s**, then try this:

`+a::SendInput, ^s`

I'd recommend that you read through the tutorial for beginners when pressing `F1` from SciTE4Autohotkey. That will help you to get started.